# Error trying to import oracle jdbc7 driver with Maven

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdbc

I cannot import the jdbc7 oracle driver with maven, I did everything like in the tutorial [Oracle Blogs](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc#pom) but I received the follow error:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.jp:database_connection_app:jar:0.0.1:  Failed to collect
>   dependencies at com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2:  Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2:  Could
>   not transfer artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7: pom:12.1.0.2 from/to
>   maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com):  unexpected end of stream
>   on Connection{maven.oracle.com:443,  proxy=HTTP @ /myProxyIP:myPort
>   hostAddress=hostAddressIP cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} 
>                     (recycle count=0): \n not found: size=0 content=... ->

A special case to me is that I'm in behind a proxy but I already configure the settings.xml file and maven can download all the dependencies except the JDBC.

In the tutorial mentioned, I didn't understand which information shall be hier...

```
<basicAuthScope>
    <host>ANY </host>
    <port>ANY </port>
    <realm>OAM 11g </realm>
</basicAuthScope>
```

Maybe this is the error source.

Here is my settings.xml...

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
<interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
<usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
<offline>false</offline>
<pluginGroups/>
<servers> 
    <server> 
      <id>maven.oracle.com</id> 
      <username>myUsername</username> 
      <password>My_Encripted_Password</password> 
       <configuration>
         <basicAuthScope>
           <host>ANY</host>
           <port>ANY</port>
           <realm>OAM 11g</realm>
         </basicAuthScope>
     <httpConfiguration>
       <all>
         <params>
         <property>
            <name>http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects</name>
            <value>%b,true</value>
         </property>
         </params>
       </all>
     </httpConfiguration>
       </configuration>
    </server> 
</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>UK</id>
      <name>UK Central</name>
      <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>default</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>myProxy</host>
      <port>myPort</port>
      <username>myUsername</username>
      <password>myPassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
<profiles/>
<activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Here is my POM...

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
          <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
          <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
            <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
     </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
            <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

The settings-security.xml is created under the same path of the settings.xml

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try to not use every thing inside <server></server> in your setting.xml

Comment: pom.xml? server.xml? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: excuse me. I already edited the question with the settings.xml and the pom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't import the library like I wanted, then I had to search for another solution:

1. Download the Jar from [Oracle Web Site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html)
2. Include Jar to maven local repository. Learned from [Mkyong Web Site](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)
3. Update Pom with the dependency

If someone have another idea, I will be happy to know that.