# java - maven - Force inclusion of JDBC4 in JAR

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/exceptions/jdbc4/CommunicationsException whenever I try to launch my application as a jar, It does not occur while launching my application from IntelliJ.

Thus I conclude this issue to being JAR Only as it works when I use it from IntelliJ, but not when I use it from the JAR.

In my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.40</version>
</dependency>
```

Basically I have everything working except when I switch over to a JAR. I think this is caused by the JAR not having access to JDBC4 how do I force the inclusion of this in the JAR?

I've tried the following solutions aswell **NONE OF THEM HAVE WORKED**:

[Error trying to import oracle jdbc7 driver with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275029/error-trying-to-import-oracle-jdbc7-driver-with-maven#39293038)

[Find Oracle JDBC driver in Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074869/find-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-maven-repository)

[Maven ojdbc configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012464/maven-ojdbc-configuration-error)

[Maven - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245102/maven-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver#29249428)

["com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure" to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963923/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has nothing to with it. You're using MySQL.

I think the problem is that your executable JAR does not have access to the dependencies.

Research how to create an executable JAR with dependencies using a Maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks you so much, you just ended 5 hours of headaches.

For anyone in the future having this issue my answer was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven#574650

Comment: Glad you found it. I would have posted it, but I answered on my phone.